# Regex - Match letters with different matching patterns

Tags: java, regex

**October 23 2016 at 10:00 AM**

From above string I needs to capture First 3 letters.

Then ignore everything until end of first word.

Finally capture everything else.

Final output should match as - **Oct 23 2016 at 10:00 AM**

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Include what you have tried and what part of it doesn't work in your question.

Comment: I tried with this, but no luck [A-Za-z]{3}([^\s]+).*

Comment: You actually described the basic layout of the expression so just try and create it. If you have problems _show_ us what you tried and we'll help you.

Comment: @Kasun you need to show some more code (add it to your question), i.e. how did you apply the expression you posted in your comment? Besides that you need a capturing group around the first 3 letters as well as allow for any length of the non-whitespace sequence that follows (i.e. `[^\s]*` or `\S*`), otherwise you'd not get a match for `May 1 2016 ...`

Comment: (tip: edit the question to include what you tried)  Your pattern started out okay: three alphabetic letters. Then it requires one or more whitespace. However your input has more letters, so you need to match those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following pattern. `$1` is the first 3 letters of the first word; `$2` is the rest of the word; `$3` is the rest of the string.

```
String input = "October 23 2016 at 10:00 AM";
System.out.println(input.replace("^([A-Za-z]{3})([^ ]*)(.*)$", "$1$3"));
```

Output:

```
Oct 23 2016 at 10:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "October 23 2016 at 10:00 AM";
var result = Regex.Replace(date, @"(\w{3})\w*( \d+ \d+ at \d+:\d+ \w{2})","$1$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will match, and give you two capture groups for extracting the desired parts.

```
^(.{3})(?:.*?\b)(.*)$
```

Each part of the pattern is [documented in the Java API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

I used a non-capture group for the part you want to discard, and a non-greedy match so that it doesn't match too many characters.  I anchored the pattern to the beginning and end of the input.  I was not restrictive at all, though, in what characters I matched: any character rather than just letters, numbers, or specific sets of characters.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
s/^([A-Za-z]{3})[A-Za-z]*(.*)$/\1\2/g.
```

Thanks.